# MySQLi Insert if values don't exist

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

EDIT: I forgot to mention that my script should not input IF a row already exists in the new DB with the same column values, that is what I mean when I refer to "duplicate entries" despite there not being a common PK.

Here's my dilemma,
I'm working with MySQLi to migrate data from an old table into a new table which have different designs and I want my program to be able to run multiple times without multiplying previous entries. My initial approach was to do a verification query for each inserted element:

```
//foreach elt of old table:
  $a = $old_table['a'];
  $b = $old_table['b'];
  $query = $db->query("SELECT `id` FROM `old_table` 
                       WHERE `a` = '$b' 
                       AND `b` LIKE '$b'")->fetch_assoc();
  if ($query == null) {
    //insert a row into the new table
  }
```

The problem with this method is that the run-time was horrendous and I managed to considerably cut it down by using a database transaction:

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO  `new_table` 
          (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`)
          VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$query->bind_param('isssi', $a, $b, $c, $d, $e);
$db->query("START TRANSACTION");
foreach ($old_table as $old_row) {
  $a = $old_row['a'];
  ...
  $e = $old_row['e'];
  $query->execute();
}
$query->close();
$db->query("COMMIT");
```

The problem with this method is that it results in multiple entries if the program is run more then once. It's important to note that since both tables have different designs, there is no common Primary Key and therefore I don't think I can use DUPLICATE KEY.

Thoughts?

Comment: $query->bind_param('isssi', $a, $b, $c, $d, $e); should come after the variables are assigned with values so you need to move it inside the loop after all old values are retrieved.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: Actually, it doesn't.  [`bind_param`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) works with references.  So, even if the variables aren't set, that line still works.  It creates the variables and references them.  (Just like `prepare()`, `bind_param()` only needs to be called once.)  When the variables are set, the references are updated, so when `execute()` is called, it works.

Comment: MySQLi fetches the values of the params upon execution so there's nothing technically wrong with this query unless I made a typo while simplifying.

Comment: my bad $query->execute(); is after all the variable assignment.. nevermind.

Comment: Are there two or more rows you could concatenate to *produce* a unique id?

Comment: @IarsAnders The new table has an auto-increment PK whereas the "old table" doesn't exist per-say, it is a set of 6 drupal tables that each have different PKs. I could produce a unique key for each entry but it wouldn't correspond to the PK of the new table

Comment: You could have two more columns on the new table called old_table and old_PK or similar. Both indexed. Eh... not ideal I know. Will you have to do this multiple times? Or can you essentially migrate once and call it?

Comment: @IarsAnders Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the new_table's design is immutable since it fits into a much larger project to build an LRS and as long as there are projects in the old system, which may be quite a while, I'll keep needing to call this script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, you already solved the problem, but for some reason stopped half-way.

> The problem with this method is that the run-time was horrendous and I managed to considerably cut it down by using a database transaction

I wonder why didn't you include select into transaction as well.

> Thoughts?

Just add select query you used to run in the first variant. That's all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Colonel, if I'm not mistaken what you're suggesting is for me to reuse the `$q = $db->query("SELECT ...") if(empty($q)) { insert }` within the foreach but is there a way for me to integrate that into my original query?

Comment: if, as you said, there is absolutely no relation between these two tables (to connect them using JOIN, for example) - then, obviously, there is no way to connect them. However, when doing such an import, if is often worth to add and `old_id` unique property to a new table.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I believe you don't *have to* use a script for this, a query would be enoguh:

```
SELECT
  /* your complex columns, from and joins go here */
LEFT JOIN `new_table` n ON n.a = old_table.a AND n.b LIKE old_table.b
WHERE
  n.a IS NULL AND n.b IS NULL AND
  /* your WHERE and LIMIT go here */
```

This approach makes use of `LEFT JOIN` which, if there is no matching row in the right table, sets all columns to `NULL` (documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html)).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't completely understood that: `there is no common KEY and therefore I can't do a DUPLICATE KEY.` so I'm not sure that you will find this useful but you can choose if you use it...

Perhaps you'll find more simple if you just try `INSERT IGNORE` :

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO new_table (a,b,c,d) 
SELECT a,b,c,d FROM old_table
```

IGNORE word will discard automatically any insert wich generates a primary o unique key conflict.

You also can directly insert from a select query. This can make things easier for this job